# Android Studio Emulator: Empty shell of a phone, no screen visible?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, mobile-development

What is wrong with my Android emulator? I'm using Android Studio and the emulator that's coming up is just a shell of an empty phone, and I can click through the middle to stuff that's "underneath" the phone, like other windows.

Android Device: Pixel 6 Pro
API Level: 33

Picture for reference:
[image]